# Go based grpc server stream keeps stacking up the response to go client

Tags: go, server, client, grpc, grpc-go

Sorry if this is a noob question, i'm new to grpc's server side streaming.

**What I have right now in a function on server that streams to client**

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", actualURL, nil)
```

//skipping some lines//
    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

```
// closing body
defer res.Body.Close()

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
```

// skipping some lines//

```
// unmarshaling the xml data received from the GET request done above
xmlDataErr := xml.Unmarshal(body, &ArrData)

// creating a variable of a custom type and creating object of specific struct Flight
var flightArrData ArrFlights
currArrData := flightArrData.Arr.Body.Flight
```

log.Println("Counting total rows to be send to the client", len(currArrData))

// looping over the response and sending streaming it to the client

for i := range currArrData {

```
    farr := &pb.FlightArrivalsResponse{
        ArrivalResponse: &pb.ArrivalFlightData{
            Hapt:     currArrData[i].HApt,
            Fltnr:    currArrData[i].Fltnr,
            Sdt:      currArrData[i].Sdt,
            Acreg:    currArrData[i].Acreg,
            Park:     currArrData[i].Park,
            EstD:     currArrData[i].EstD,
            Gate:     currArrData[i].Gate,
            AblkD:    currArrData[i].AblkD,
            ActD:     currArrData[i].ActD,
            Callsign: currArrData[i].Callsign,
        },
    }

    senderr := stream.Send(farr)

    // skipping some lines //
}
```

// returning nil once done
    return nil
}

**The issue i am facing**
On the client side I have function that receives this response, sleeps for n number of minutes and ask for the response again.

Client do get the response as expected in first call, however for every subsequent call something strange happens and that is my current issue, I try to illustrate in the form of every subsequent calls below :

Call 1 from Client to Server --> Server returns 200 rows

*client sleep for n minutes*

Call 2 from client to Server --> Server returns 400 rows!! (basically every row twice as in 200 + 200)

*client sleep for n minutes*

Call 3 from client to Server --> Server returns 600 rows!! (200+200+200)

**Summary**

I do check for error == io.EOF on the client side and only way right now to stop this stacking up of response from server to client is to stop the server and restart.

I am not sure what am I missing here to make sure that I am only sending the actual and exact response that i have received from the GET request. Would greatly appreciate any hint on this.

**More information**

Part from gRPC protobuffer def in proto file

```
rpc GetFlightArrivals (FlightArrivalsRequestURL) returns (stream FlightArrivalsResponse) {
    };
```

**Complete code for the server side impl of above gRPC**

```golang
func (s *Server) GetFlightArrivals(url *pb.FlightArrivalsRequestURL, stream pb.Flight_GetFlightArrivalsServer) error {

    cData := ch.ConfigProcessor() // fetches the initial part of the URL from config file

    if url.ArrivalURL == "" {
        actualURL = cData.FURL + "/arr/all" // adding the arrival endpoint

    } else {
        actualURL = url.ArrivalURL
    }

    // build new request to get arrival data
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", actualURL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Recheck URL or connectivity, failed to make REST call")
    }
    req.Header.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "text/plain")
    req.Header.Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
    req.Header.Add("app_id", cData.AppID)
    req.Header.Add("app_key", cData.AppKey)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml")


    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    // closing body
    defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to get any response")
        return err
    }
    // unmarshaling the xml data
    xmlDataErr := xml.Unmarshal(body, &flightArrData)
    if xmlDataErr != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to unmarshal arrival xml data see error, ", xmlDataErr)
        return xmlDataErr
    }

    currArrData := flightArrData.Arr.Body.Flight
    log.Println("Counting total arrivals in Finland", len(currArrData))
    log.Println("Starting FlightDeparturesResponse for client")
    for i := range currArrData {

        farr := &pb.FlightArrivalsResponse{
            ArrivalResponse: &pb.ArrivalFlightData{
                Hapt:     currArrData[i].HApt,
                Fltnr:    currArrData[i].Fltnr,
                Sdt:      currArrData[i].Sdt,
                Acreg:    currArrData[i].Acreg,
                Park:     currArrData[i].Park,
                EstD:     currArrData[i].EstD,
                Gate:     currArrData[i].Gate,
                AblkD:    currArrData[i].AblkD,
                ActD:     currArrData[i].ActD,
                Callsign: currArrData[i].Callsign,
            },
        }

        senderr := stream.Send(farr)

        if senderr != nil {
            log.Fatalln("Failed to stream arrival response to the client, see error ", senderr)
            return senderr
        }

    }
    currArrData = nil
    log.Println("Attempting to empty the arrival data")
    return nil
}
```

**Test case for checking above impl of gRPC**

I just start a test grpc server and make call to that grpc in this test case. Implementation on the client is same around receiving the data.

```golang
func TestGetFlightArrivals(t *testing.T) {
    const addr = "localhost:50051"
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(addr, grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Did not connect: #{err}")
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    f := pb.NewFlightClient(conn)

    t.Run("GetFlightArrivals", func(t *testing.T) {

        var res, err = f.GetFlightArrivals(context.Background(), &pb.FlightArrivalsRequestURL{ArrivalURL: ""})
        if err != nil {
            t.Error("Failed to make the REST call", err)
        }

        for {
            msg, err := res.Recv()
            if err == io.EOF {
                t.Log("Finished reading all the message")
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                t.Error("Failed to receive response")
            }
            t.Log("Message from the server", msg.GetArrivalResponse())

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently your example code has large holes in it (e.g. you unmarshall into ```ArrData``` but that data is never used) which makes it difficult to comment.

Comment: @brits I will get back with that soon.

Comment: Your explanation is not enough, but I bet you are using a pointer and not destroying it. You may be using the same pointer again and again, duplicating your rows.

Comment: I have edited my question with full code and a test case calling that impl, is this what you were looking in terms of the additional info?

Comment: @rubens21 i am not sure what you exactly mean with duplicating, I was expecting that send on server and receive on the client should empty the stack on server side. I have added more info now to my question.

Comment: I even tried setting 

`currDepData = nil` 
since that is the variable that is getting the full struct - still the same issue

Comment: ok i think i found the struct that needed to be set to nil, at least tests so far seems promising, thanks @rubens21

Comment: @sup What's been printed out by the log "Counting total arrivals in Finland"? The backend code looks right.

Comment: Also, you should close the stream from the client side if you do not have anything else to send. I don't think it will create the issue you are describing, but it is a good practice.

Comment: @rubens21 that log prints out the total number of rows that I need to process, basically the list of flight arrivals. Based on what you said I had to add just these two lines 
`var emptyArrData ArrFlights` which is basically the complete XML struct and assign this empty... var `flightArrData = emptyArrData`

I am just doing server side streaming in this case, client closing stream would mean Client streaming to server (or bidi-streaming) ? So likely I don't have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from @rubens21 I added following lines 
`var emptyArrData ArrFlights` which is basically the complete XML struct and assign this emptyArrData to the struct `flightArrData = emptyArrData`